# Python tkinter how to update label text from a cascaded context menu

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I am having trouble figuring out how to update label text from a cascaded context menu.  I've got the menu, but I can't get the labels to update with the text I want.

```
def main_context_menu(self):
        self.mnu1 = tk.Menu(self.main_frme, tearoff=0)
        self.mnu2 = tk.Menu(self.main_frme, tearoff=0)
        self.mnu1.add_cascade(label='Overwrite Type', menu=self.mnu2)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Bar Beer', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Store Beer', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Vapors', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Cigarettes', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Gas', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Misc.', command=self.context_menu_command)
        self.mnu2.add_command(label='Bills', command=self.context_menu_command)

def do_context_menu1(self, event):
        try:
            self.mnu1.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        finally:
            self.mnu1.grab_release()

    def do_context_menu2(self, event):
        print('go')
        self.c_type = event.widget
        print(self.c_type)

def context_menu_command(self):
        self.lblt.configure(text=self.c_type)

self.lblt = tk.Label(self.grid_frme, text=exp_type,
                        width=13, height=2, bg='white')
        self.lblt.grid(row=self.row, column=2)
        self.lblt.bind('<Button-3>', self.do_context_menu1)
        self.mnu2.bind('<Button-1>', self.do_context_menu2)
```

That is the business end excerpt from a larger script.  It's what I've tried.  The labels don't update.  What am I doing wrong?  Sorry about the formatting.  Copy and paste BS.  I don't have the time to properly indent here.

Comment: You don't have time to properly indent here, but we should take our time to answer your question?

Comment: Also why does why don't you use different commands for ` self.mnu2.add_command(..., command=...)`? Or pass in a parameter?

Comment: After further investigation, it appears the label text is not getting updated because my label ID variables are being reused dynamically.  I'm populating labels from a database.  The label variable is being reused up to 30 times.  How can I workj around this without having a unique label variable name for each label?

Comment: @CoolCloud I'm sorry, I'm frustrated, but is the code readable?  No flame war.  That answer was coming from a place where you are being difficult.  An unnecessary response.

Comment: Thanks, @TheLizzard.  I will try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Alright, thanks @TheLizzard.  I was able to get a unique label to update with each different context menu command, but these recycled label variable names are not updating.  So, the problem is with that, a separate issue than what I posted originally, so I will start a more specific topic.  New post.

Comment: @malonn Ok. Also to update a label's text use: `<tkinter.Label>.config(text=...)`

Comment: Tracking 100%, @TheLizzard.  The problem is this:
`label = tk.Label(text='test')`
`label.grid()`
gets generated 10's of times, and config breaks when it updates cuz the label variable is reused.  I'm currently googling...

Comment: @malonn I am confused. You don't have that line of code in your question. Also I think you only create the labels once and then use `.config(text=...)` to change its text.

Comment: Sorry @TheLizzard.  My question was kinda answered by you already, but it brought up the real problem I have now.  I'm gonna post a separate thread once the time has elapsed.  Now I can't get the label to update because each label is assigned the same variable name.  So calling `label.config(text='test')` updates the last of dozens of same named labels.  I fear I have to create a unique name for each label.  Labels are generated in a for loop using the same label name.  The for loop is of variable length, so I can't assign a unique name.

Comment: @malonn Ok last thought before I wait for the new question that you are going to post: store the labels in a list.

Comment: Ooo, @TheLizzard.  That sounds promising.  I didn't think of that little gem.  Let me see what I can come up with...